# How to use pom version in shell command in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to get pom.xml version within Jenkinsfile and then use that version in a shell script.
This gives the exception `bad substitution` when trying to use `pom.version`. What is the correct syntax to pass the pom version?

```
script {
    def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'

    withCredentials(...) {

        sh '''#!/bin/bash                                        
              cp "${WORKSPACE}/target/stats-${pom.version}-shaded.jar" /xyz
        '''
    }                   
}
```

I installed `Pipeline Utility Steps` plugin for `readMavenPom` cmd but didn't restart Jenkins. Is it necessary to restart Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to substitute `${pom.version}`, you need to use GString. The triple-quote you used defines a multiline Java string that does not support variables substitution. You need to replace `'''` with `"""` to define a multiline GString that can substitute both variables, `${WORKSPACE}` and `${pom.version}`.