# How to access groovy variable from pipeline into shell script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've a global variable in pipeline say `BACKUP_DIR_NAME` and in shell script which is inside pipeline, I want to build path using it hence have following code -

```
BACKUP_DIR_NAME="10-04-2020"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('First') {
            steps {
                script {

                    sh '''
                       BACKUP_DIR_PATH="/home/oracle/SeleniumFramework/SeleniumResultsBackup/"$BACKUP_DIR_NAME"/"
                        echo "Directory path is "$BACKUP_DIR_PATH
                        '''

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executed this, I can see value of `BACKUP_DIR_NAME` is evaluated as empty. Could you please help me to correct above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pom version in shell command in jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971483/how-to-use-pom-version-in-shell-command-in-jenkinsfile)

Comment: I tried answer for the above suggested question. But results into error - `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BACKUP_DIR_PATH for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variables from Jenkinsfile to shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539076/how-to-pass-variables-from-jenkinsfile-to-shell-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix two types of variables in your `sh` step. In the first line, you are trying to access the Groovy variable and interpolate its value to construct shell variable. In the second line, you expect to access this shell variable.

To satisfy the first part, you need to use double quotes to construct a Groovy string that supports variables interpolation. To satisfy the second part, you need to escape `\$` to prevent `$BACKUP_DIR_PATH` from being interpolated.

```groovy
BACKUP_DIR_NAME="10-04-2020"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('First') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                       BACKUP_DIR_PATH="/home/oracle/SeleniumFramework/SeleniumResultsBackup/"$BACKUP_DIR_NAME"/"
                        echo "Directory path is "\$BACKUP_DIR_PATH
                        """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped! Thanks for detailed explanation to understand things clearly.